# Forcing dplyr to evaluate passed symbol / quosure when conflicting with existing column name

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval, quosure

## Problem

I want to string of a column name to `dplyr::arrange` in a form `am <- "cyl"`. The purpose is to sort by column **`cyl`**.

## Desired outcome

```
dplyr::arrange(mtcars, cyl)
```

## Attempts

```
am <- "cyl"
```

### 1) `rlang::quo`

```
dplyr::arrange(mtcars, !!rlang::quo(am))
```

*Sorted by `am` not `cyl`.*

### 2) `rang::ensym`

```
dplyr::arrange(mtcars, !!rlang::ensym(am))
```

*Sorted by `am` not `cyl`.*

### 3) Culry Curly

```
dplyr::arrange(mtcars, {{am}})
```

*Not sorted.*

---

## Background

In actual function I'm sorting data frame by index column I'm creating. The variable with column name is called `index_column`. I want protect myself from, albeit highly unlikely, scenario of actual data containing `index_column`. I could solve that using `make.names` and scanning for unique column names but I'm more interested in solving the problem above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be `sym`

```
out2 <-  dplyr::arrange(mtcars, !!rlang::sym(am))
```

-testing with OP's expected

```
out1 <- dplyr::arrange(mtcars, cyl)
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way is to use `.data`:

```
dplyr::arrange(mtcars, .data[[my_variable]])
```